# Netlify CMS isn't including the hyphen when saving as .yaml format

Tags: gatsby, netlify-cms

I'm using Gatsby with `gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms` to add Netlify CMS to the website, `netlify-cms-backend-fs` to allow Netlify CMS to work in development mode using the file system instead of a remote repo, and `gatsby-transformer-yaml` to transform the yaml file so it can be accessed via GraphQL queries.

Here's the relevant code:

```
// src/cms/cms.js
import CMS from "netlify-cms-app";

/** Netlify CMS config */
const config = {
  load_config_file: false,
  media_folder: "static/img",
  public_folder: "img",
  collections: [
    {
      label: "Business Details",
      name: "business",
      files: [
        {
          label: "Contact Information",
          name: "contactInfo",
          file: "data/business.yaml",
          fields: [
            { label: "Title", name: "title" },
            { label: "Business Name", name: "name" },
            { label: "Phone Number", name: "phone" },
            { label: "Email", name: "email" }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

/** Change to file system backend for development  */
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  const FileSystemBackend = require("netlify-cms-backend-fs");
  config.backend = {
    name: "file-system",
    api_root: "/api"
  };
  config.display_url = "http://localhost:8000";
  CMS.registerBackend("file-system", FileSystemBackend);
} else {
  config.backend = {
    backend: {
      name: "test-repo" // To be changed to repo when ready for deployment
    }
  };
}

CMS.init({ config });
```

I'm able to access the Netlify CMS dashboard, create a new entry, and publish it. However when it's published, the content of `data/business.yaml` is:

```
title: Business Details
name: My Business Name
phone: 555-5555
email: me@example.com
```

This **should** instead be formatted as (note the hyphen and indentation):

```
- title: Business Details
  name: My Business Name
  phone: 555-5555
  email: me@example.com
```

The result of this is that I'm unable to query this data using:

```
query MyQuery {
  allBusinessYaml {
    edges {
      node {
        email
        name
        phone
      }
    }
  }
}
```

as `allBusinessYaml` doesn't exist.

**This error is resolved if I manually change the `data/business.yaml` file to the correct format with hyphens and indentation.**

I've tried setting the widget as `object` or `list`, and have tried explicitly setting `format` and `extension` to `yaml` however that doesn't solve the issue either. e.g.

```
const config = {
  load_config_file: false,
  media_folder: "static/img",
  public_folder: "img",
  collections: [
    {
      label: "Business Details",
      name: "business",
      files: [
        {
          label: "Contact Information",
          name: "contactInfo",
          file: "data/business.yaml",
          format: "yaml",
          extension: "yaml",
          widget: "list", // NOTE: I've also tried using "object" here
          fields: [
            { label: "Title", name: "title" },
            { label: "Business Name", name: "name" },
            { label: "Phone Number", name: "phone" },
            { label: "Email", name: "email" }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netlify CMS doesn't yet support top level lists - here's the issue to follow: https://github.com/netlify/netlify-cms/issues/531